# MAP Estimation of Covariance Matrix of a Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian, covariance, parameter-estimation

I have a general prior multivariate normal distribution and I want to update it with new samples which are more local for my case. I want to do it with MAP estimation. With MAP estimation it is possible to find a relation for new mean vector, however I could not find a general expression for the covariance estimation. Is there a general way of estimating covariance matrix in the framework of MAP estimation, or I need to have some assumptions and specific cases for estimating it?

Comment: did you check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution ??

Comment: You can place an inverse Wishart prior on the covariance matrix, and this gives you a conjugate posterior for the covariance, with both the mode (MAP) and mean in closed form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution#Conjugate_distribution